# Why am I getting this "Connection to PulseAudio failed" error?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I have a computer that runs Mythbuntu 12.04. It has an external USB Kenwood Digital Audio device.

When I open up pavucontrol, I get this message:

[image: pulse error]

If I do as the message suggests and run start-pulseaudio-x11, I get this output:

```
$ start-pulseaudio-x11
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

Error log file, created with [these intructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio/Log), on [Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1123653/).

How do I correct this error?

Comment: what happens when you ask 'pulseaudio --check'

Comment: @DrSAR: I get absolutely no response from that command. It immediately returns to the prompt.

Comment: As the dialog suggests, what happens when you execute start-pulseaudio-x11?

Comment: @William: I added the results when executing start-pulseaudio-x11 to the question.

Comment: `ps auxw|grep pulse` output?

Comment: @DaveMG please follow the procedures [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio/Log) and give us the output.

Comment: @BrunoPereira: I followed the instruction. The ~/pulseverbose.log is kind of huge, though. How should I upload it?

Comment: pastebin.com allows that.

Comment: I had the same problem and the cause was that I edited the /etc/pulse/default.pa file and added a module in it. I simply #commented out that entry, logout, login, then it was back.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The solution to this problem was discovered in the course of solving my [other problem, with Pulseaudio and Flash](https://askubuntu.com/a/170014/17041).

First I needed to completely purge and reinstall Pulseaudio. One way to do this is to run the command:

```
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install pulseaudio
```

Then, *after* I had a clean start, I discovered there was this odd entry in `/etc/pulse/client.conf`. It had a line that said:

```
autospawn = now
```

It seems that `now` is not a valid option. I have no idea where that option was coming from, as I thought I was starting fresh after reinstalling.

I changed it to `yes`, and then commented it out as well anyway.

```
; autospawn = yes
```

Rebooted, and then I was able open `pavucontrol` without errors.

The lesson I took from this is that purging an application might not be as complete as one would assume it to be.

Comment: Someone discovered HOW that `autospawn = now` ended up there? Could it be another instance of sabotage in Linux? 20 upvotes to a mysterious "not valid option installed as default" is, at least, very strange, isn't it?

Comment: Guess: `autospawn = no` is valid, and perhaps someone used `nano`, then missed the `Ctrl` on `Ctrl+w` to write, just after they changed `yes` to `no` and the cursor was still sitting there.

Comment: Uncommenting `; autospawn = yes` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
rm -r ~/.pulse
rm -r ~/.pulse-cookie
rm -r ~/.config/pulse
```

There might be errors reported that files could not be found. That's ok.
Then we kick pulse and start it again:

```
sudo pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

There, too, errors might be reported like:

```
E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Home directory not accessible: Keine Berechtigung
W: [autospawn] lock-autospawn.c: Fehler beim Zugriff auf Autostart-Sperre.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to acquire autospawn lock
```

But after a reboot, it worked for me. Pavucontrol is again running fine since then.

Comment: The above steps helped me for an issue in Fedora where a bluetooth headset was immediately disconnecting every time after connection, with error about ad2p protocol being unavailable. Thanks so much @Peterling!

Comment: Try also `pulseaudio -v` for verbose output!

Comment: The two commands.......'sudo pulseaudio -k' and 'pulseaudio --start' worked for me. After pulseaudio --start I can do 'pactl info' to confirm if pulseaudio is working or not

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you've tried deleting ~/.pulse/* and restarting the sound server?

Your second option is to check /etc/pulse/client.conf in /etc/pulse, as suggested in the warning. Make sure everything is set to its default value by commenting out every line with a leading semicolon.

Finally, it could be related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/207312). The work-around here was to start pulseaudio in system mode, by changing the value of PULSEAUDIO_SYSTEM_START in /etc/default/pulseaudio to 1. This will prevent pulseaudio from loading 'default.pa' in your /etc/pulse folder. If this fixes your problem and you are on a multi-user system so don't want to continue running pulse in system mode, then edit your post with the contents of default.pa. Otherwise, just leave it fixed. I don't really see the problem with running it in system mode on a single-user system.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've deleted ~/.pulse/* and restarted the sound server. I set PULSEAUDIO_SYSTEM_START to 1. I've set everything in etc/pulse/client.conf to be the default value. I've rebooted after every change to ensure they took hold. Unfortunately, none of them have fixed the problem.

Comment: It's my pleasure.

What model is your audio device? Do you get sound at all out of it, or is it just pavucontrol which are giving this error?

Comment: ps. could you also post the result of
    
    'cat /var/log/syslog | grep pulseaudio'

Comment: Deleting ~/.pulse and starting pulseaudio fixed my problem - when I was inserting my USB headset (Logitech G35) it caused the built in speakers to be removed from the devices list in the sound manager as well as not working itself.

Comment: Solved mine, too! The problem arose when the bluetooth headset ran out of battery!

Comment: ovangle, deleting ~/.config/pulse (and restarting pulseaudio) solved the same problem I had on Fedora!! many thanks! you saved my day.

Answer (score 5):

I received this `"Connection to PulseAudio failed"` error when there were different values of the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` environment variable.

The `pulseaudio` server was running with one value, and `pavucontrol` was running with a different value.  Consequently, `pavucontrol` was looking in the wrong directory for the communication socket created by `pulseaudio`.

In this case, the solution is to make sure both processes have the same value for the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` environment variable.

Comment: You are my hero, I was using a crontab script to start OBS and couldn't get OBS to connect to audio server, OBS would only has audio if I start it in the desktop environment but not from my server, this solved my issue!

Answer (score 4):

Open `etc/pulse/default.pa` and try commenting out all these lines:

```
.ifexists module-jackdbus-detect.so
load-module module-jackdbus-detect
.endif
```

Run the steps again and check the log for changes, if possible give use another output.

If that does not work remove `pulseaudio` and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this on an old gentoo computer I was upgrading.  It turns out I had failed to start the `dbus` service

```
# /etc/init.d/dbus start
# rc-update add dbus default
```

This will probably be an unusual cause of that error dialog.