# Detect media play / pause events

Tags: sound, headphones, automation, playback, media-buttons

I want to pause playback after headphones have been unplugged, then resume after they were plugged back in.

My current solution uses ACPI to detect plug / unplug, as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640741/what-code-is-executed-when-headphones-are-disconnected/642404#642404). To play / pause the playback, I use `xdotool key XF86AudioPlay`.

**This solution works fine in the basic case:**

- music is playing, headphones are plugged in
- headphones are unplugged -> music pauses
- headphones are plugged back in -> music continues playing.

However, I do *not* want to resume playback if it wasn't active **when** the headphones were unplugged.

**Imagine this scenario:**

- start up the PC with headphones in,
- play music,
- pause music,
- unplug headphones,
- plug headphones back in.

The last point is where the problem lies – the playback would resume after the headphones are plugged back in, although it was not active at the time they were unplugged.

Moreover, `xdotool key XF86AudioPlay` simply toggles the playback, whereas `xdotool key XF86AudioPause` does nothing. That makes things even worse:

- start PC with headphones in,
- play music,
- pause music,
- unplug headphones *(MUSIC STARTS PLAYING!)*.

---

So what I need is to **detect play** / **pause** / **stop events** as well as plug / unplug events, to be able to correctly react in all possible scenarios.

This state machine describes the desired operation:
[image: Unplug-pause FSM]

---

The one idea that came to my mind is to re-bind the keyboard shortcuts for play / pause / stop to add the state machine logic. This has the drawback that playback *always* has to be controlled using these keyboard shortcuts, instead of eg. Rhythmbox buttons, which is somewhat impractical.

Also, if I close Rhythmbox while playing, the state machine will stay in a `playing` state. Of course I could have a 'daemon' which will wait until Rhythmbox is closed, and then set the state to `stopped`. But what if it's not Rhythmbox that plays the music, what if it's for example VLC, etc.? This approach is ugly and unreliable, so I would like to avoid it.

---

**My question:** How to detect when media playback was paused / resumed / stopped?

Comment: According to [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142859/does-pulseaudio-have-an-error-log) , you can enable a verbose for pulseaudio. By there you are able to view these events. Next step is to develop a tool (sniffer) to track them Just seeding an idea. I'm thinking about a tool to automatically change playlist at certain time, but only after actual music ends...