# Can I get any logging and error output from Flash?

Tags: flash

To further provide better information for [my other question about browsers and Pulse audio](https://askubuntu.com/q/122148/17041), I wanted to see if I could get some kind of helpful log information.

I've looked at logs from both Pulseaudio and Firefox, but don't see anything like an error in either of them.

The problem I'm experiencing may be coming from Flash. Is there a way I can trap specifically any log output from Flash?

---

Update:

I've downloaded the [Linux Flash Player 10.3 Plugin content debugger](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html), and I've installed `libflashplayer.so` in `~/.mozilla/firefox/plugins/`, and copied the `user/*` files to `/user`. I've also set up mm.cfg to say:

```
ErrorReportingEnable=1
TraceOutputFileEnable=1
MaxWarnings=50
TraceOutputFileName=/home/dave/.macromedia/Flash_Player/Logs/flashlog.txt
```

And I rebooted just to be sure everything was starting fresh.

However, after playing a Flash video from Youtube, flashlog.txt is not being generated.

How can I be sure that logging is in fact enabled, so I can tell whether I'm simply not getting errors or I haven't set up logging correctly?

Answer (score 4):

The location for the logs is:

```
/home/username/.macromedia/Flash_Player/Logs/
```

You have to have logging enabled. [Take a look at this.](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fc9.html)

This will explain the way you can find out the error in using flash or flex as the front end for your applications.  By default flash/flex‘s logger is not enabled.  That means it wont log the errors raised to any file. You need to enable the logger.

[This is from the Adobe site.](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/configure-debugger-version-flash-player.html) It explains how to configure the debugger version of Flash Player for all operating systems including Linux.

Create a file named “mm.cfg” in the following locations:

```
home/username/mm.cfg
```

Open the newly created mm.cfg file in a text editor and add the following text:

ErrorReportingEnable=1
TraceOutputFileEnable=1

The flashlog.txt file will be created in the following location:

```
home/username/Macromedia/Flash_Player/Logs/flashlog.txt
```

Comment: I have a `/home/username/.macromedia/Flash_Player/` directory, but there is no `Logs` directory within it. There are are only two directories, `macromedia.com` and `#SharedObjects`.

Comment: Thank you for the update on how to enable logging. I created the configuration file as instructed, but it doesn't seem to be generating the logging output. I tried rebooting in hopes that whatever process that is responsible for Flash would initialize with logging, but that didn't work either. Is there something else I need to do in order to ensure Flash starts logging events?

Comment: Those this work?

Comment: If my memory serves me right, and it usually does, it did work.

Comment: Both the links in this answer have decayed. Can you put the instructions for enabling logging into the answer directly?

Answer (score 2):

> Hope this helps too (for the sake of google search it came from):
>
> In order to do trace, you need the debugger version of Flash Player
>   from http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html (look for
>   "debugger" version specifically - they are hard to spot on first look)
>
> Then an mm.cfg file in your home containing
>
> ErrorReportingEnable=1 TraceOutputFileEnable=1 MaxWarnings=50
>
> And then you are good to go - restart the browser. When traces start
>   to fill in, you will find the log file in
>
> ```
> ~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/Logs/flashlog.txt
> ```
>
> Something like
>
> ```
> tail ~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/Logs/flashlog.txt -f
> ```

<sup>Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825316/flash-trace-output-in-firefox-linux</sup>