# How do I get rid of this module-combine error in Pulse Audio

Tags: pulseaudio

I've been [having problems with my Pulse Audio server](https://askubuntu.com/q/122148/17041), and recently while investigating, I came across these error messages in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jul 20 09:16:40 mythbuntu pulseaudio[6555]: [pulseaudio] module.c: module-combine is deprecated: Please use module-combine-sink instead of module-combine!
Jul 20 09:16:40 mythbuntu pulseaudio[6555]: [pulseaudio] module-combine.c: We will now load module-combine-sink. Please make sure to remove module-combine from your configuration.
```

I looked in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` for any mention of `module-combine`, but did not see any. Also, I searched the web for elements of the error message and only got links to bug reports with vague discussions.

How do I get rid of this `module-combine` error?

Comment: If you could not find `module-combine` did you add `load-module module-combine-sink` to your `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

Comment: @damien: Thank you for responding. `load-module module-combine-sink` is not in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`. If I add it, can I add it to anywhere in the file? Or does it need to be at the end of the beginning...?

Comment: just place it down the end of the file.save and restart to take affect

Comment: @damien: Thanks. I did that, but I still get the same `please make sure to remove module-combine` error. Also, I now get a new error: `[pulseaudio] module-zeroconf-publish.c: avahi_entry_group_add_service_strlst(): Local name collision`

Comment: For now perhaps undo the changes and ill look into it a bit further for you

Comment: OK maybe `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-zeroconf` then also load both modules again as described before with `load-module module-combine-sink`

Comment: @damien: Sorry, I'm a little confused. I'm very much an end-user for sound configurations. I'm not sure what you mean when you say "load *both* modules". I thought I only had to load one module with `load-module module-combine-sink`. What other module do I need to load? (Also, I'm now away from the computer, so I'll have to attempt this a little later.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is in the 'paprefs' package, which on the 'Simultaneous Output' tab controls loading the 'module-combine' module.  It has not been updated to use the 'module-combine-sink', and the 'module-combine' is now a dummy module that simply warns and then loads the 'module-combine-sink'.

You can change the module loaded by the paprefs setting by using 'gconf-editor' and changing 'system/pulseaudio/modules/combine', the 'name0' key should have 'module-combine-sink' value instead of just 'module-combine'.

In theory there are two bugs:

1. 'paprefs' shouldn't be using 'module-combine'
2. 'paprefs' should migrate to 'dconf'

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

From the pulseaudio **warning** we can see that some script or application tries to load the deprecated `module-combine`. This however will not do any harm to your pulseaudio setup as pulseaudio has a fallback mechanism to load the `module-combine-sink` instead. Of course this will not be done without a warning in the logfiles.

If you really want to get rid of this message you will have to investigate places where this module may be loaded. One possibility is your `/etc/pulse/default.pa` which could also be located in `~/.pulse/default.pa`. Another possibility is `/etc/pulse/system.pa` in case we run pulseaudio system-wide, or an older version of paprefs.

However any application may load a pulseaudio module at runtime. We have no experience on Mythubuntu, and have no idea which applications you may have installed. It may be therefore be worth to check what application have just started when the warning message appears, and see if any of those have a configuration file where we need to replace the `module-combine` by `module-combine-sink`.