# How do I get my sound card back?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I have been fighting [an annoying problem with my sound set up](https://askubuntu.com/q/122148/17041) for a while now, and it's suddenly taken a turn for the worst. I don't know if this situation is related or not, but I think it might be a new problem, so I'm starting a new question.

As described in my [other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/122148/17041), every time I start a YouTube (or any online video), I have to restart my Pulseaudio server. However, this last time I did it, my Pulseaudio server never came back.

When I look at my sound settings, this is all I get:

[image]

This is what my sound settings were before:

[image]

How do I get my sound device back again?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that the server, when rebooting, was not completely logging in automatically to the right user account.

I was not aware of this, but apparently for the Pulseaudio server to become available on the network, the right user has to be logged in on the server. I would have thought for the machine to be on would be enough.

Anyway, this has been resolved by ensuring the server is logged in to the correct user account after each reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe pulseaudio isn't running or not running correctly. Try removing the pulsaudio configuration by renaming (for safety) the ~/.pulse directory (it's in your home folder).  This will cause it to generate a new setup next time.  This procedure got it back for me when it failed when I removed a pulseaudio equalizer module I was trying out.