# Flash keeps crashing, possibly sound problem

Tags: flash

Flash crashes constantly, regardless of whether or not I use Firefox, Chrome, or Chromium.

It does not always crash, but I would estimate it crashes 4 out of 5 times when loading a page. It seems to be most likely to happen on pages that have more than one Flash item. It also happens when Flash has to make a transition of some sort. For example, when Youtube switches from an advertisement to the main video, then it might crash. Also, some sites are more likely to crash than others. Vimeo will crash with almost 100% reliability. Youtube is fairly stable, and crashes maybe one out of five times.

I have tried uninstalling and [reinstalling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player) Flash. I have tried the [Flash-Aid plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/ja/firefox/addon/flash-aid/), but none of the options it presented helped (in fact, it always ended up simply removing Flash and not finding an installation candidate).

I think it might have something to do with how Flash is connecting to Pulse. Part of the reason I suspect sound is a problem is that I had to get help to get Flash to work with my sound before.

As far as I understand it, all that's different about my sound system is that I go over a network to connect to a Pulse sound server on a different machine, and that I've hardcoded the server IP and port by adding a line that says `PULSE_SERVER=192.168.0.4:4713` in the file `/etc/environment` on the client machine. That's basically it, I think, but for more specifics, there are details [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/170014/17041).

Unfortunately, it seems that Flash doesn't like this set up. It's maddening to have Flash be so unstable, so I hope someone can advise on how I might diagnose and solve this problem.

Comment: I am not saying that this is impossible to solve, but, like many proprietary programs (OS-independent), Flash gives you very few options for diagnosing or fixing this kind of problem.  The best that you can do is send a bug report to Adobe and hope that they fix it.

Comment: @InkBlend: I actually doubt the problem is with Adobe. Flash works fine on three other computers of mine, and the one where the problem is, it has a particular sound set up.

Comment: @DaveMG - probably wise to describe exactly the sound setup you have for this PC with the flash issues.  Should hopefully give someone a clue as to the issue.  Is this restricted to one user - or if you create another account, does it still occur? (i.e. system wide vs local)

Comment: @fossfreedom: I'm certainly not opposed to describing my sound set up. The only hold back is that I'm not totally sure I understand it fully myself. A very helpful member of AskUbuntu more or less set it up for me, and, other than the fact that Flash is crashing like a North Korean rocket, I'm hesitant to tinker with it. I will endeavour to work out what pertinent details to provide.

Comment: @DaveMG Do you experience this issue if you uninstall flash and view videos with html5 protocol instead?

Comment: @desgua: HTML5 video seems to work alright. As does sound in other software like Banshee. But not all content on the web is available in HTML5, so I think I still need to work out what it is that makes Flash fail.

Comment: @DaveMG I am not suggesting you not to use flash, just trying to narrow down the bug ;-) Have you tried the Flash Player debugger http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html ?

Comment: Flash has serious problems with tabs, iframes, and the same javascript being hooked/tied to both flash objects.  Ad driven promiscuous sites often crash flash for this reason(they all use the same js ad trackers).

Comment: @desgua: I think I've installed the Flash debugger. However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to get any report or log from it.

Answer (score 0):

Which version do you use?
Have you installed the correct version of `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.
I had a problem more or less similar to this but got fixed when I reinstalled the correct version of `U-R-E` from the software center.