# Ubuntu Server virtual audio

Tags: server, sound

I wanted to know how to configure a server with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to make it a platform for audio streaming via another program.

I think that there are no drivers installed, and being a server even the device.

I checked with the command lspci the presence of audio devices, and I have not found.

Comment: You don't need an audio device for streaming audio. As long as you stream audio over a network, a network interface will do.

Comment: yes, but if for example I wanted to capture the music from spotify to make sure that you hear on Ventrillo or teamspeak?

Comment: But that is a much more specific question. They have different ways of transferring audio. Ventrilo uses Virtual Audio Cable and for this you will need an audio device. I couldn't find out how Teamspeak streams audio as their documentation site is down, but in any case I couldn't find a mention of Virtual Audio Cable.

Answer (score 5):

You can use PulseAudio to pipe outputs of most of Linux applications to other applications.

Run `pactl load-module module-virtual-sink sink_name=insertsomefancynamehere` in your Terminal.

Install pavucontrol and run it. You should see all applications connected to PulseAudio server. Make sure application you want to stream (eg. Spotify) is playing something and is visible in Playback tab.
 [image]

Change it's output to virtual sink you've created. Now click Recording tab and to the same for application that is used to do streaming (eg. TeamSpeak).

TeamSpeak should hear Spotify now :D

Comment: pactl load-module module-virtual-sink sink_name=insertsomefancynamehere
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/70560/why-am-i-getting-this-connection-to-pulseaudio-failed-error Does this help?