# Virtual Audio Cable For Ubuntu

Tags: sound, virtualization

I am looking for a Virtual Audio Cable program to pipe audio through.  Surely there must be a Linux version or something similar to these awesome Windows programs...

- http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm
- http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/index.htm

I looked and found one called vsound for Linux...

- http://www.vsound.org/

But it hasn't been updated in almost 11 years so yeah.

I had thought JACK was the answer, but it is rather difficult to use.  I mainly want a virtual soundcard that works in conjunction with a hardware soundcard.

Comment: Like this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/461050/ubuntu-server-virtual-audio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Create a Virtual Microphone on Linux with Pulseaudio...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Goeucg7A9qE&t)

Comment: Dude, you really should explain the answer in full rather than using a video.

Answer (score 12):

One virtual audio cable (VAC), that's free, open source and works on Linux, Windows and OSX is [jackaudio](http://jackaudio.org/).

You can download the source code from [here on the jackaudio website](http://jackaudio.org/downloads/)

You can install it via `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install jack
```

A GUI tool to use with it is qjackctl

```
sudo apt-get install qjackctl
```

See also [this blog post](http://programminglinuxblog.blogspot.com/2011/07/virtual-audio-cable-linux-and-windows.html) for more information

Comment: I am starting to think JACK will not do what I need.  All I really want is to have a virtual audio input and audio output device listed when I go to Sound Settings.  I'll play with JACK some more and see if it will do this or not later today.

Comment: try `gladish`  or `patchage` that will show connections between jack and other things

Answer (score 10):

To make virtual audio devices that work like virtual audio cables, you can use PulseAudio commands. I make a pair of them to allow two software defined radio apps (eg: WSJT-X or JS8Call) to communicate bidirectionally with each other for testing purposes without needing any hardware:

```
pactl load-module module-virtual-sink sink_name=VAC_1to2
pactl load-module module-virtual-sink sink_name=VAC_2to1
```

The device names after sink_name are arbitrary, just make them unique.

In app1:

- Input device: VAC_2to1.monitor
- Output device: VAC_1to2

In app2:

- Input device: VAC_1to2.monitor
- Output device: VAC_2to1

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an alsa loopback device, which Ubuntu uses Alsa as its primary back end. The effect trickles down to PulseAudio, so it's 100% compatible.

It's just one command:

```
sudo modprobe snd-aloop
```

Tada, from there you will have a virtual audio device. Playing to it as input will result in its output, just as VAC does. However, in pulse audio, it will also show up named as, "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" - this is probably a bug needing to be fixed in pulse audio. But you'll notice there are two of them, one will be your virtual/loopback device.

This is just temporary, but if you want to make it permanent, then add it to your /etc/modules files.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create a virtual audio cable on Linux. Setting it up is very different, but it will function somewhat the same way as on Windows.

## PulseAudio

If you use [PulseAudio](https://github.com/GordijnMan/Virtual_Audio_Cable_Linux/blob/main/PulseAudio.md), you'll need to use `pacmd` to create a loopback interface and set its monitor as an input interface to your application: `pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=VAC`. This doesn't work with every application (they don't always detect monitor devices).

You then need to create a combined output channel to listen to your desktop audio while splitting this to your new VAC: `pacmd load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=MAIN slaves=<PREFERRED SINK>,VAC`.

Then, you can add your microphone input to this channel: `pacmd load-module module-loopback sink=VAC source=<MIC> latency_msec=1`. The latency is really up to you. If you sound choppy, go higher.

## Cadence

[Cadence](https://github.com/GordijnMan/Virtual_Audio_Cable_Linux/blob/main/Cadence.md) is another option, and you'll probably need it with realtime permissions.

It can create a virtual audio connector using JACK as its backend.
It allows you to save your patchbay and Studio session, which can save a lot of time. Especially if you need to launch additional shell commands.
All you need to do is configure your microphone at `Configure -> Driver -> Device`.

I have a more elaborate explanation on [GitHub](https://github.com/GordijnMan/Virtual_Audio_Cable_Linux/blob/main/README.md).