# Virtual Audio Sink (Virtual Audio Cable) on Ubuntu

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Is there any equivalent of Virtual Audio Cable driver for Windows that works on Ubuntu? I wanna stop using Windows at all but this is very important for me cause I host a TS server so I can connect all audio from my devices and listen it with 1 headset on my main machine. I even have a script that opens and connects my devices on boot (but this is off topic). I searched web for any solutions and I found these: https://www.onetransistor.eu/2017/10/virtual-audio-cable-in-linux-ubuntu.html
and [Virtual Audio Cable For Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633674/virtual-audio-cable-for-ubuntu)
but they don't work with TS or even Discord. Is there anything else I can try.
P.S. Maybe I could configure JACK to do it for me but I don't really know how to handle JACK

Comment: Basically I would like to use system sounds as audio input (so system would treat this as mic)

Answer (score 5):

Pulse Audio allows you to create virtual sinks.

```
#Start pulseaudio daemon
pulseaudio -D
#Create a virtual sink (the software that is the source of your audio will output to this sink)
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=vspeaker sink_properties=device.description=virtual_speaker
```

Pulse audio naturally creates a source for this sink called vspeaker.remote which you can remap as a virtual mic.

```
pactl load-module module-remap-source master=vspeaker.monitor source_name=vmic source_properties=device.description=virtual_mic
```

Now open up pavucontrol and assign the software that is the source of your audio to output to vspeaker. Assign Discord or whatever else you want to route this audio to, to use vmic as a mic.

Some more info is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257992/how-can-i-use-pulseaudio-virtual-audio-streams-to-play-music-over-skype).

The link you've given uses alsa-loopback - similar, but probably more complicated to use than pulse audio.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to a Teamspeak server, you could use a TeamSpeak 3 client.

Or you could use other audio streaming software, like
[Music Player Daemon (MPD)](https://www.musicpd.org/) which is a mature server-side application, under active development.
There is long [list of available clients](https://www.musicpd.org/clients/).

Other options are listed [here](https://www.linuxlinks.com/musicservers/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm sorry but your links aren't working for me.

Comment: @MartinKnayt - Please check now