# bluetooth headset connects but not showing in sound settings

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I was able to listen with my BT headset, but suddenly, one day, it disappeared from sound settings forever!

I've even re-paired my headset (and its connected already) but it doesn't have any options in sound settings in order to listen from it.

When I try this command:

```
hcitool scan
```

It doesn't find any devices! Even this command:

```
pactl list cards short
```

Only lists my default sound card only! What should I do?

Comment: Not an answer to this question, but I found this question when searching for my problem and maybe my comment helps others aswell; I saw my bluetooth sink in `pactl list short sinks` and was unable to play music with it. Disconnecting via bluetoothctl and requesting the default agent (thus typing `bluetoothctl`, then `disconnect`, then `default-agent`, and then `connect [device]`) helped me.

Comment: I had this issue just now with a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 and new Sony buds, and the solution for me was... try repairing a third time. Didn't show up in sound settings the first two times, but did on the third. No idea why.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this command:

```
sudo -H pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

I run this whenever I have paired, and successfully connected, but still can't see them in sound settings. It essentially tells pulseaudio to load reload it's list of bluetooth devices.

Comment: In what situations would you use this command?

Comment: @belacqua Whenever I can't see my headset in the sound settings.

Comment: You might consider adding a little more context -- people just seeing this command probably have little idea what it does, whether it's sketchy, whether it needs to be repeated on reboots, etc..

Comment: Why was this answer accepted? What caused the problem to begin with, and what's the long-term fix? Ubuntu bluetooth worked perfectly for me, and then after a power outage it stopping working entirely. This command fixes it, but having to manually run this command every time I want to use bluetooth **is not a solution**. I've downvoted this answer until more explanation is provided.

Comment: @Cerin, okay, what do you want to know? It works - you admited that - if it was helpful you should upvote. It was accepted because it solved the OP's problem. If it solves it **it is a solution**.

Comment: I'm having this same problem on Ubuntu 14.04. However, this solution did not work for me.

Comment: @Cerin ? You didn't explain it - any suggestions for how to improve the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: @Tim, It doesn't solve the problem because the problem comes back almost immediately.

Comment: I would disagree. Solving is: *"effectively dealing with a problem"*. While this is a temporary solution, it is one, and it does, if temporarily solve it. Why not add it to `cron`?

Comment: @Tim, You don't fix a flat tire by putting a piece of scotch tap over the hole... This issue recently re-emerged for me in 14.04, and even this no longer "fixes" it. If we knew the underlying problem, we could find a better solution.

Comment: @Cerin If you can automatically reapply the scotch tape when it falls off what's the difference?

Comment: @Tim, For your car's sake, I really hope you're just trolling me. Regardless, this appears to be an [unresolved bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1274613) in pulseaudio.

Comment: @Cerin Are you using Blueman or the default Bluetooth Manager?

Comment: I am getting this error: "Failure: Module initialization failed". Can anybody help?

Comment: This didn't work for me. Syslog: [pulseaudio] module.c: Module "module-bluetooth-discover" should be loaded once at most. Refusing to load.

Comment: Not solving the problem for me. `module-bluetooth-discover` (as well as `-policy` and `bluez5-discover`) gets loaded automatically. Still no sinks in pavucontrol besides the built-in speakers, and "1 card(s) available." in pacmd/pactl `list-cards`.

Comment: seems like the permanent solution is given in the answer below.  I upvoted it and down-voted this one.

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti the last update to that repository was 90 weeks ago - nearly 2 years. That is not a solution for 16.04 - in fact it hasn't worked since 15.04.

Comment: sorry.. I will upvote again.

Comment: I get the following error: `No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused`

Comment: @Startec I’m afraid I no longer even have an Ubuntu computer, never mind have this issue!

Comment: I'm getting "Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
"

Comment: For Ubuntu 22.04 with PipeWire check this: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Troubleshooting#missing-bluetooth-profiles

Comment: Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused

Comment: @Max https://askubuntu.com/questions/70560/why-am-i-getting-this-connection-to-pulseaudio-failed-error

Answer (score 32):

Extending upon Mark's answer, which basically did the trick for me.

The problem is that the bluetooth service tries to load the pulseaudio bluetooth module at startup, which fails because they require X11 to be running. You need to change the configuration so that the pulseaudio bluetooth module is loaded after X11.

1. *Tell the bluetooth service to not load the module.* To do this, edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and comment out these lines by putting `#` characters in front of them:

   ```
   .ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
   load-module module-bluetooth-discover
   .endif
   ```
2. *Configure the module to be loaded after X11.* To do this, edit `/usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11` and add two lines:

   ```
   if [ x"$DISPLAY" != x ] ; then
       # ...

       # Add these lines:
       /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
       /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect
   fi
   ```
3. *Restart pulseaudio and bluetooh*. Either reboot your machine or use the following commands:

   ```
   pulseaudio -k
   start-pulseaudio-x11
   sudo service bluetooth restart
   ```

This way, the pulseaudio bluetooth module should be working and Volume Control (`pavucontrol`) should detect the bluetooth device and list it under input and output devices.

Comment: The above doesn't work for me; instead, I get start-pulseaudio-x11 
/usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11: 24: /usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11: /usr/bin/pact1: not found

Comment: @user1945827 : it's "pactl", not "pact1". It stands for PulseAudio Control.

Comment: @static_rtti thanks.  I managed to get it working.

Comment: I'm voting up but all I needed was to `sudo service bluetooth restart`

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me after a full system reboot (restarting the service didn't work. I am on Arch linux and all was well until I did a full system update last week. The only thing that isn't working is the output selector in the top right of Gnome, it doesn't show multiple outputs, just one. So I have to open sound settings to choose it, but at least it is in the list now.

Comment: This does not work in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: The three commands of step 3. saved me a reboot on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Thaaanks, works perfectly <3

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04 with my Pixus Bluetooth headphones.
The ubuntu Bluetooth manager saw the headphones and correctly connected them, but ALSA didn't see them.

You can check the list of Bluetooth devices by command

```
bluetoothctl devices
```

and you can check what outputs ALSA has by command

```
pactl list sinks short
```

The solution that I found is to set option ControllerMode to bredr in file /etc/bluetooth/main.conf

```
# Restricts all controllers to the specified transport. Default value
# is "dual", i.e. both BR/EDR and LE enabled (when supported by the HW).
# Possible values: "dual", "bredr", "le"
#ControllerMode = dual
ControllerMode = bredr
```

When you changed the option restart Bluetooth service

```
sudo gedit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

Then connect headphones again and check that ALSA sees it. If so then it must be shown as the available output in ubuntu sound settings

```
pactl list sinks short
enter code here
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I still have some problems. When my headphones automatically connected, I don't see them in sound settings. but if I reconnect them in settings manually then they appear in sound settings.

Comment: Works for me also in Debian 10

Comment: This worked for me, thank you.

Comment: It was enough just to restart bluetooth module with sudo systemctl restart bluetooth

Comment: This was the only answer which worked for me with the same problem on Ubuntu 22.04 and a pair of Sony WH-1000XM4.

Comment: This worked exactly for me as mentioned. should have been mentioned as top answer

Comment: Can't believe this worked. I was so skeptical after having tried different things and it seems surprising that "dual" is wrong.

Answer (score 14):

The headset is properly paired and shows under Bluetooth Devices but it does not show as an available INPUT / OUTPUT source for audio.
The problem is that the pulseaudio bluetooth module is loaded before X11, changing a couple of config files do the trick:

PulseAudio can not load bluetooth module 15.10/16.04

`nano /etc/pulse/default.pa`

Comment out the following lines:

```
#.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
#load-module module-bluetooth-discover
#.endif
```

`nano /usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11`

Find the following lines and add after them:

```
if [ x”$SESSION_MANAGER” != x ] ; then
/usr/bin/pactl load-module module-x11-xsmp “display=$DISPLAY session_manager=$SESSION_MANAGER” > /dev/null
fi
```

Add the following lines:

```
/usr/bin/pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
/usr/bin/pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

This way the Pulse audio’s Bluetooth modules will not be downloaded at boot time but after x11 is started.

Comment: Is there some service that needs to be restarted for these changes to take effect?

Comment: You can trigger them on the command line as in the answer above .... my post is how to have it automate on startup.

Comment: I think you're saying that if you type the three `/usr/bin/pactl` commands at the command line, they'll take effect immediately. It also looks like the two to add to `/usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11` should be inside the `if` statement. Can you confirm both of these observations? Thanks!

Comment: The lines are inserted after the shown `if..fi` but within the larger `if [ x"$DISPLAY"...fi`. Yes, you should be able to execute the commands directly in terminal.

Answer (score 8):

I am not able to comment on the top response, but I thought I'd add that on my Ubuntu MATE 12.04 LTS Laptop, I had to do:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

only then did this work

```
sudo -i pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Then I had to go into bluetooth manager app, pair the device, then set to 'Audio Sink' mode, then I could see the device within the Ubuntu Sound options and manipulate inputs/outputs!

Answer (score 6):

The permanent solution  would be to add the blueman PPA and update your package to the latest version which has the bug fixed: https://launchpad.net/~blueman/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blueman/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That way, you should no longer have to run the

```
sudo -i pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

command every time but only once. Works for me on 14.04 LTS (Trusty)

[Source](http://www.lxle.net/forums/discussion/503/how-to-sink-audio-a2dp-to-your-bluetooth-headset/p1)

Comment: This does not apply for 16.04. The repository has no release candidate for it.

Comment: @k0pernikus Seems like you can just `sudo apt install blueman` directly in 16.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/764273/ubuntu-16-04-wont-output-sound-to-bluetooth-headphones

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 23.10 disabling wireplumper did it:
`$ systemctl --user disable --now wireplumber`