# can't connect bose QC 35 after pulseaudio bluetooth update on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

After updating pulseaudio to 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1 on Xenial, bluetooth audio stopped working. After attempting a re-pairing it seems like bluetoothctl connects to the device, then disconnects.

```
[NEW] Device 04:52:C7:09:F9:C1 The Ox
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:09:F9:C1 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:09:F9:C1 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:09:F9:C1 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:09:F9:C1 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:09:F9:C1 Paired: yes
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:09:F9:C1 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:09:F9:C1 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:09:F9:C1 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:09:F9:C1 RSSI: -73
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:09:F9:C1 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:09:F9:C1 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:09:F9:C1 RSSI: -60
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:09:F9:C1 RSSI: -75
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:09:F9:C1 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:09:F9:C1 RSSI: -58
```

This used to work on 1:8.0-0ubuntu3 and the update on Thu, 03 Nov 2016 16:58:35 +1100 to 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1 broke it. Attempting to revert the update will try to downgrade my gdm and gnome-shell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pair Bose QuietComfort 35 with Ubuntu 16.04 over Bluetooth](http://askubuntu.com/questions/833322/pair-bose-quietcomfort-35-with-ubuntu-16-04-over-bluetooth)

Comment: I tried the suggestions there with no luck.  I think my problem is different since mine used to work but stopped working after an update

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that several reboots didn't fix it but unplugging the USB Bluetooth dongle and re-plugging it back in did help. I read this fixes also weird behaviors with microsoft wireless mice. I do not know why this fixes it but it did.