# Pair Bose QuietComfort 35 with Ubuntu over Bluetooth (2)

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

(Relating to [Pair Bose QuietComfort 35 with Ubuntu over Bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833322/pair-bose-quietcomfort-35-with-ubuntu-over-bluetooth) - seems to be "too old to response to")

This is really frustrating!

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and am unable to get sound in the headphones. I have tried all suggestions above without success. I have had it working before I reinstalled Ubuntu, but unfortunately I have not noted how I made it working then. Now I can pair, at least from the Ubuntu side what it seems, but there is no voice in the headphones indicating that a pairing has been made and the sound is still coming out from the computer's speakers.

```
[bluetooth]# pair 04:52:C7:5F:CB:A9 
Attempting to pair with 04:52:C7:5F:CB:A9
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:5F:CB:A9 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:5F:CB:A9 UUIDs: 00000000-deca-fade-deca-deafdecacaff
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:5F:CB:A9 UUIDs: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:5F:CB:A9 UUIDs: 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:5F:CB:A9 UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:5F:CB:A9 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:5F:CB:A9 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:5F:CB:A9 UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:5F:CB:A9 UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:5F:CB:A9 Paired: yes
Pairing successful

[Joachim Bose QC 35]# connect 04:52:C7:5F:CB:A9 
Attempting to connect to 04:52:C7:5F:CB:A9
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:5F:CB:A9 Name: Joachim Bose QC 35
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:5F:CB:A9 Alias: Joachim Bose QC 35
Connection successful
[Joachim Bose QC 35]# info 04:52:C7:5F:CB:A9 
Device 04:52:C7:5F:CB:A9
Name: Joachim Bose QC 35
Alias: Joachim Bose QC 35
Class: 0x240418
Icon: audio-card
Paired: yes
Trusted: yes
Blocked: no
Connected: yes
LegacyPairing: no
UUID: Vendor specific           (00000000-deca-fade-deca-deafdecacaff)
UUID: Serial Port               (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Bose Corporation          (0000febe-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
Modalias: bluetooth:v009Ep400Cd0134
[Joachim Bose QC 35]#
```

Comment: Have you selected the headphones in **System Settings** > **Sound**?

Comment: They are not there! The only thing I have there is the built-in sound

Comment: Please edit to include results for `pactl list short | grep blue`

Comment: eperjoa@elxa6gwlq72:~$ pactl list short | grep blue
8 module-bluetooth-policy  
9 module-bluetooth-discover  
10 module-bluez5-discover

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with a bluetooth (BT) headset, my solution was:

- Open bluetooth (BT) manager (it should show a list with all BT defined)
- If yours is not there,
- Set the headphones(hp) to 'discover mode' and run a Search on the BT manager
  This should discover the hp and they should appear now. They may not connect though, in that case:
- Right-click on the hp name and select headset, this may still not produce sound,
- Right-click again on the hp name, this time there will be a new option, 'audio profile'
- Select High Fidelity Playback (A2DP sink)
- Now open your 'Sound Settings' and select your headphones and adjust volume.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The headphones are there, but there is not context-menu when I right click the hps. They are shown with a Bluetooth symbol on the right. Before I have seen it has had a headphone symbol. Not that I know if that makes any difference anywhere in the system...

Comment: I got some hint to update bluetoothctl (I think); https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-bluetooth/msg69764.html. But I cannot find out how to do that... any idea?