# Bose QuietComfort 35 bluetooth headphones disconnect after a few seconds in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: bluetooth, 17.10

My Bose QuietComfort 35 bluetooth headphones disconnect after a few seconds in Ubuntu 17.10. 
They used to work fine under Ubuntu 16.04. After a restart, the same thing happens again. I can not reconnect the headphones without restarting.

I tried to use the solutions for the pairing problem ([Pair Bose QuietComfort 35 with Ubuntu over Bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833322/pair-bose-quietcomfort-35-with-ubuntu-over-bluetooth)), but the problem persists. Also, as far as I have seen the other questions concerning these headphones, this seems to be a different problem.
This is the result for the service bluetooth status after the phones disconnect:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service  
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)   
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-12-09 22:34:21 CET; 1min 58s ago   
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)   
 Main PID: 742 (bluetoothd)   
   Status: "Running"   
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)   
  CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service   
          └─742 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd   

Dez 09 22:34:21 mycomputer systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...   
Dez 09 22:34:21 mycomputer bluetoothd[742]: Bluetooth daemon 5.46   
Dez 09 22:34:21 mycomputer systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.   
Dez 09 22:34:21 mycomputer bluetoothd[742]: Starting SDP server   
Dez 09 22:34:21 mycomputer bluetoothd[742]: Bluetooth management  interface 1.14 initialized   
Dez 09 22:34:30 mycomputer bluetoothd[742]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource   
Dez 09 22:34:30 mycomputer bluetoothd[742]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink   
Dez 09 22:35:08 mycomputer bluetoothd[742]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_04_52_C7_31_07_DE/fd0: fd(37) ready  
Dez 09 22:35:54 mycomputer bluetoothd[742]: Start: Connection timed out (110)   
Dez 09 22:35:56 mycomputer bluetoothd[742]: Abort: Connection timed out (110)
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Has anyone solved this? Please help...

Comment: I also have exactly the same problem! Any solution to this yet?

Comment: it just suddenly worked with me, I don't know why. Maybe some update. I hope it still works with Ubuntu 18.04 when it comes out next week ;)

Comment: @sebastian: It looks like It's not only Bose which is having a problem. My headphone was having the same issue additionally it always used to connect to HSP/HFP instead of A2DP until I restart my computer. For many days I used a workaround using a script which you can also try from here:
https://gist.github.com/pylover/d68be364adac5f946887b85e6ed6e7ae. 
Later I install `blueman` and always used my headset to connect using it. I still don't know how it fixed the issue but I don't have to restart my system anymore.. Lol!

Comment: I paired my device with `blueman` and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

What helps for me (Ubuntu 18.04) is do remove the device in the Bluetooth settings and then reconnect. After that, the connection is stable.