# Where is startup files include pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth

Every time I reboot my Ubuntu 16.04 I need to run manually this command `sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` before I can connect to my bluetooth headphone or I get error "Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: Protocol not available..."

What file should I add this to make sure this command is run during startup?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://askubuntu.com/a/833323/393832  You can also try installing the following packages:     bluez, bluez-cups, bluez-obexd, gnome-bluetooth, indicator-bluetooth, libbluetooth3:amd64,l ibgnome-bluetooth13:amd64, pulseaudio-module-bluetooth. Got the list here (german ubuntu wiki): https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Bluetooth/Einrichtung/

Comment: Adding ControllerMode = bredr did not help

Comment: Did you try to install the other packages? They should create a startup-script for bluetooth for you. Then you just need to setup your connection to your headphones using the System Settings > Bluetooth dialog

Comment: All of these packages are already installed and newest versions

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `bluez` package:

```
sudo apt-get install bluez
```

A startup-script called `bluetooth` gets created in your `/etc/init.d` folder.
Also don't forget to enable bluetooth:
Go to `System Settings -> Bluetooth`

Comment: It did not help. Where exactly to add it in this file? I added it to the case start like this

        log_progress_msg "${DAEMON##*/}"

        run_sdptool || :
        pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
        if test "$HID2HCI_ENABLED" = 1; then

Comment: I didn't edit this file. It was generated by one of the bluetooth packages