# Bluetooth Headphone paired but not recognized as sound card (KDE Neon - 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth, kde, headphones

I was using my bluetooth headphones (Bose QC35II) as usually but this week I had to unpair it and when I paired it again it didn't get recognized as a sound card anymore. The headphone remains with a intermittent light like is trying to connect but the system shows it as connected.

Other bluetooth stuff like a mouse and a keyboard are working and pairing with no problems.

I don't know what happened, maybe a kernel or firmware update?

System Info:

- KDE Neon based in 16.04
- kernel 4.15.0-32-generic
- KDE 5.13.4
- Wifi/Bluetooth Intel 8265

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in other post:

[Pair Bose Quietcomfort 35](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833322/pair-bose-quietcomfort-35-with-ubuntu-over-bluetooth)

Looks that is some problem with the Bluetooth LE tech. Just disable it before pair does the job