# Zoom on Ubuntu very small

Tags: zoom-meeting

I've installed Zoom on my Ubuntu yesterday and it worked fine.

Today, the screen suddenly is very small and the fonts are tiny!!!

[Very tiny Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U45Ow.png)

I am new to Ubuntu, trying to leave Windows. Unfortunately everything in Ubuntu seems very nerdy and a lot of things have to be done through command line. [And I couldn't get my Bose Bluetooth Headphones to work either](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292166/how-to-connect-my-bose-headphones-to-ubuntu-through-bluetooth).

Why is it, that after 20 years of Linux this stuff hasn't improved and you have to be a computer expert just to use it? I don't have to be a car mechanic in order to drive my car!!

Update: I just realized, that you can not see the tininess of Zoom in the screenshot, because it gets enlarged. But believe me, it IS really tiny.

Comment: Insulting the people you are trying to get help from? Interesting strategy.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I am just so sick of this technocrazy world. And it get's worse and worse. Just the new normal. And I am not insulting the people. If you feel insulted, because you take it personally, you don't get the point. You are not Ubuntu, are you? I am not talking about you, or anybody here, I am talking about Ubuntu as a representation of the technocrazy in this world. Instead of being a shining light, that would make things better, it adds to the technocrazy. Why is that? No wonder why the whole world is still using Windows, because it's the only thing people can somewhat understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, you just have to be a computer expert, than you can solve everything on Ubuntu. If you are not, good luck...

This is the solution that worked for me:

- Open a terminal
- Type cd ~/.config
- nano zoomus.conf
  (For the non-computer experts: nano is a text editor)
- change the parameter autoScale=false to autoScale=true
- Press ctrl+x and save the changes

This does not explain at all, why it worked yesterday, without me changing any parameters.

In the car analogy this would be like: Suddenly the car only goes backwards. Users would completely accept that as normal, would google for hours and hours how to fix it, open the hood, plug some cables into different holes, and voila! the car would go forward now.

And nobody would be complaining about that. You would just see often people on the highway, having their hood open, and trying to fix "unexpected errors"

Comment: I had a flat tire on the way in this morning, I also had to do an oil change recently. That being said he is right that Ubuntu is a pain in the ass. I have to fix something in Ubuntu way more often than the most unreliable car I ever owned. And some things I just can't fix and have to accept that some things just won't work and have to live without it.
This isn't Ubuntu's fault in most cases tho it's lack of drivers or developer support, however, doesn't change the fact you have to keep getting your hands dirty every 20 miles.

Comment: This worked perfectly on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: The `autoScale` parameter was already set to true in my computer, but everything looked too small nonetheless. Anyway, I was able to fine tune the scaling by changing `scaleFactor`, in my case 1.2 was what I needed.