# Unable to pair Bose QC35 headphones after following fixes (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, headphones

Firstly, let me begin by saying I have followed two guides I've found to fix this issue to no avail.

[Pair Bose QuietComfort 35 with Ubuntu over Bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833322/pair-bose-quietcomfort-35-with-ubuntu-over-bluetooth#)

[Ubuntu 20.04 bluetooth not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231074/ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-not-working#1238076)

I can see my Bose headphones on the device list as a non-LE audio device, however it still fails to pair, saying "Failed to connect: Host is down".

I should also say that this particular computer (desktop) does not connect to these headphones when I am running Windows 10 either, though the headphones pair easily with my Surface Pro 5 without any trouble. I don't know if this is simply a bluetooth driver issue or hardware issue, but it's SUPER annoying that this is the only computer I can't use these headphones with.

I do not have a dual boot setup, so I don't know if that makes a difference. My Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 operating systems are on separate SSDs, and I simply turn off the computer and switch the sata cables from one to another when depending on which I want to use (super technical, I know).

Any help is greatly appreciated, I just want to use my **** headphones!!

Answer (score 1):

The QC35's work with my ubuntu 20.04 +- OK

I've not done anything special to my setup

I see two bluetooth headphones (they're called Think White Duke)

1. LE-Thin White Duke
2. Thin White Duke

only the Thin White Duke connects

[image]

I can't use the microphone and headphones of the QC35 at the same time for some reason - if I select the QC35 microphone, the headphones go to some kind of low-quality mono-output

If I use other microphone (internal laptop one) then the QC35 headphones work OK

In the sound setting I have this :

[image]

[image]

when I select as microphone the QC35 microphone then the headphones change -
still sound - but mono and low quality

Comment: I tried this before even attempted the two fixes I listed above. The issue was my bluetooth didn't even list the headphones as an option to connect. Furthermore, I don't have the drop down configuration menu in my sound panel like you do in the picture you provided.