# Ubuntu Bose QC 45

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth, headphones

I have a pair of Bose QC 45 headphones. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on my PC. I didn't originally have a Bluetooth adapter, so I bought a UGREEN CM390. It works great out of the box, I even tried it with my phone.

The problem is in connecting the headphones to the computer.  I can see them through the Bluetooth interface, but when I try to connect them to the computer, it just says they are connected. But in fact, they aren't (no voice confirmation that they are connected).

What I've tried so far:

- All the steps in this question: [Pair Bose QuietComfort 35 with Ubuntu over Bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833322/pair-bose-quietcomfort-35-with-ubuntu-over-bluetooth)
- Download the `blueman` program and connect through it.
- Manually remove the device and reconnect it using `bluetoothctl`.
- Use the Bose music app and turn on pairing mode to find the new connection.

If you have any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: "But in fact, they aren't." Is it that they aren't connected, or that the audio doesn't go to the headphones?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant the headphones aren't connected. When they connect I usually get a voice notification from them. But the funny thing is that my computer considered them connected. I also tried just pairing them (via blueman) but I had the same result.

Comment: The following worked for me for 35II: download the bose app on your phone, if you don't have it already, click on add new device. It'll prompt you to put the headphones in pairing mode. Once you put it in pairing mode, it appears on the list. Hope this works for the 45 too.

Comment: Hi, @sodiumnitrate. I did this. Unfortunately, it didn't help (I see my headphones in the list of Bluetooth devices, but I can't connect to them - when you try to connect it only says "connected", but in reality, I didn't receive a voice confirmation). It's also strange that I see my computer in the Bose app connection list, but I can't connect to it manually.