# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - Intel AX210 Adaptor, Bluetooth Problem

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker, wireless-keyboards

I see that many people having problems around same things but I wasn't able to solve my problem by examining them. I bought a custom pc with rog crosshair x670e hero motherboard which has Intel AX210 as Blutooth adaptor and the supported driver seems to be installed. However I can't connect to bluetooth devices even tough they appear in the device list.

JBL Flip 5: It rarely connects and even if it connects it doesn't give sound or give out of sync and low quality sound

HP 350/355 multi-device-bluetooth-keyboard: Can't connect remains as "Not set up" in the list or gives a window that has the pairing number but dissappears in a matter of second.

Ubuntu version:

```
lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Kernel Version:

```
uname -r
6.2.0-35-generic
```

Adaptor:

```
lspci -nnk
.
.
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz [8086:0024]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
.
.
```

```
$ lsusb
.
.
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. AX210 Bluetooth
.
.
```

```
drivers:
ls /lib/firmware/intel/ | grep ibt-0041
ibt-0041-0041.ddc
ibt-0041-0041.sfi
```

```
sudo dmesg | grep Blu
[    4.588446] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.588462] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.588464] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.588466] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.588469] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.667153] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware timestamp 2022.5 buildtype 1 build 38020
[    4.673885] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-0041-0041.sfi
[    4.673893] Bluetooth: hci0: Boot Address: 0x100800
[    4.673896] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware Version: 132-5.22
[    4.673897] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware already loaded
[    5.385074] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.385077] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.385080] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.385851] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[   19.775291] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   19.775295] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   19.775298] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  345.172075] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x 401 failed: -16
[  454.285254] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x 401 failed: -16
```

Even if I manage to connect the keyboard, it would connect and disconnect rapidly then finally disconnect for good. I believe that is the reason why even If I connect the prompts on the screen is delayed or the key presses gets missed.

Comment: Please attach output of `lsusb` command

Comment: "firmware is "intel/ibt-0041-0041.sfi" which is different than the iwlwifi does this look wrong?" It does not look wrong. The ucode firmware is for the wifi and the sfi is for bluetooth. Normal. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/833322/pair-bose-quietcomfort-35-with-ubuntu-over-bluetooth/833323#833323

Comment: Thank you @chili555! I tried the method from the link but I was unable to get any sound from the jbl or maintain a connection on the keyboard.