# Bluetooth headset Sony ZX770BN

Tags: bluetooth, headset

I have some problems with my Bluetooth headset. It works fine if I connect it when Ubuntu runs via an installation medium in trial mode. After installation, it is not possible to connect it anymore. It works fine with my Android phone and with another Windows computer. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Best regards

Comment: Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/767168/125220) fix your problem?

Comment: This is a pulseaudio/bluez bug and a fix is being worked on