# Autoconnecting seamlessly to Bluetooth headset (Sennheiser Momentum M2 AEBT) in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, headset

I own a Bluetooth headset (**Sennheiser** Momentum M2 AEBT). I am having an issue with autoconnection, for which I have found a workaround. I would prefer a real solution.

If I want the connection to work, I have to

1. Connect the headset.
2. Edit the Bluetooth settings, select audio profile "Headset Head Unit"
3. Disconnect the headset.
4. Connect the headset.
5. Select "High fidelity playback" as the audio profile.

Then everything is peachy.

Here are alternate scenarios I've tried:

1. When the headset and the computer autoconnect, the computer will use the most recent profile (High Fidelity Playback). However, VLC will play muted audio, and MPD will be persistently paused.

   If I try turning the profile to "off", then back to "High Fidelity Playback", I get the error message `Failed to change the profile to a2dp_sink`, and I see the same problems as before. The same situation occurs if I change the profile to "Headset Head Unit", then try switching to "High Fidelity Playback".
2. You can see in the images that there are three options: "Headset", "Handsfree" and "Audio Sink". It does not seem to matter which one I click.

Here are screenshots with descriptions.

Available menu options in Bluetooth:

[image]

Persistent pausing in MPD. I can move forward or backward, but there is no "play" option:

[image]

VLC will happily play with no audio:

[image]

Comment: It's a problem with pulse audio

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? And what Desktop Environment?

Comment: Do you still have this issue? If so, please [edit] the output of `lspci` and `lsusb` to your post. If not, please share your resolution with the community here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The following solution worked for me:

1. Check to see if the `module-bluetooth-discover` is loaded: 
   `pactl list short | grep blue`
   If it's not in the list then:
2. Load the module:
   `pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover`

You might want to reload it even if it is in the list. Then, try to connect again to the audio sink for High Fidelity sound.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried various [proposed methods](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764273/ubuntu-16-04-wont-output-sound-to-bluetooth-headphones), but the only at least half-automatic solution for me was using the [a2dp.py](https://gist.github.com/pylover/d68be364adac5f946887b85e6ed6e7ae) script as described already in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239209/no-sound-from-bluetooth-headset-but-its-detected#answer-837732).

It does the steps mentioned in your question, but you have to run it each time you want to connect, and you need to pass a number to it to select the bluetooth device.

You could define a launcher (right-click on panel, select `Panel Preferences...`) which runs a small wrapper script to call `a2dp.py` and pass it the number of the bluetooth devices list that your headset typically has. For me, that number doesn't seem to change. Here my sample script `run_a2dp.sh` (adapt for your device number):

```
#!/bin/sh
# run a2dp.py and pass it a fixed device selection number
a2dp.py <<EOF
<your number here>
EOF
```

If you have both `a2dp.py` and this `run_a2dp.sh` on your `$PATH`, you can click the launcher whenever you want to connect with the headphones. It takes a few seconds for `a2dp.py` to finish the configuration, but it works for me.

At least no more fumbling around or running terminal commands to get it done...