# Sound from bluetooth headphones (airpods) only works for 1 second after connecting to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, headphones

I've paired my Apple Airpods (bluetooth headphones) with my Ubuntu 18.04 installation running on my Lenovo Thinkpad Edge. Whenever I connect the sound plays for about 1 second then stops. Once this has happened the headphones are still connected and the audio output is still going to them, but I can't get any sound to come out without disconnecting and reconnecting, when the same thing happens.

Any ideas? One weird thing is that when I change the volume with the headphones connected it says 'Headphone' instead of the normal 'Headphones' (though changing the volume doesn't do anything anyway.)

Comment: I've just solved this by using this answer. https://askubuntu.com/a/836202/265089

Comment: Hi, have you fixed this issue? Is your Airpods microphone working on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes I fixed it, see the link I posted above.

Comment: Sorry to insist... with the microphone?

Comment: Yes microphone works too