# Connecting with Google Home via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker, bluez

If I try to connect to my Google Home Mini via bluetooth, by saying "Okay Google Bluetooth Pairing", the connection just fails. If I do `pair [mac-address]` via `bluetoothctl`  it just tries to pair infinitely.

EDIT: after a timeout bluetootctl displays `Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled`

Comment: thats understandable

Comment: EDIT: after a reboot, it just reverted back to it's not working state

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the problem, but I don't know why connecting this simple device like with Google Home via Bluetooth has difficulties getting it to work in Linux.

[bluetooth headset connects but not showing in sound settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481951/bluetooth-headset-connects-but-not-showing-in-sound-settings/1301449#1301449)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1318511)