# Use google home as a bluetooth speaker

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I dualboot my PC with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18. With Windows, I can use a google home mini as a bluetooth speaker for the PC. But when in Ubuntu, I can't get it to work:

1. After bluetooth connection is established, I only see a `dummy output` in the Settings->Sound->Output, which doesn't do anything
2. As I kept trying disconnect/reconnect bluetooth and restart PC, very rarely I see google home correctly shows up in the sound output list. But it still doesn't play sound.
3. Only ONE time, I was able to at least play test sound in the Settings->Sound. But I couldn't play sound in youtube videos. And I could never reproduce this case anymore.

---

There is a similar question. But it doesn't seem to attract much traffic. I try to provide more detail here. [Connecting with Google Home via Bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/997633/connecting-with-google-home-via-bluetooth)

Comment: With 20.04, google mini is by default listed in "input" section of sound settings. This answer fixes the issue: https://askubuntu.com/a/1301449/66023