# Ubuntu Mate bluetooth headphones connected but do not appear in sound settings & bad sound quality

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

I am running a freshly installed version of Ubuntu Mate on my PC and I can't get my bluetooth headphones to play any sound. They appear as a connected device in my bluetooth settings but they're not showing in the sound settings output.
Also the sound quality in general is terrible and i don't know what causes this problem.

I don't have much experience with Ubuntu so please keep that in mind in your answers.
I already found that question ([bluetooth headset connects but not showing in sound settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481951/bluetooth-headset-connects-but-not-showing-in-sound-settings)) but I wasn't able to solve my problem with the answers given.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your Ubuntu MATE version? Is it 20.04 LTS or latest 21.10? What have you tried? Do you see handset in Blueman?

Comment: My Version is 20.04.3 LTS. And yes, i can see my headphones in blueman. But it seems like alsa doesn't recognize them. I tried to change ControllerMode to bredr in file /etc/bluetooth/main.conf  and restart my bluetooth service.

Comment: I was playing around with the bluetooth settings and it seems like I have found a solution. After I connected my headphones to bluetooth and after they already appeared in blueman, I clicked the bluetooth Button in my panel, selected "recent connections" and than selected "Auto connect profiles on [device name]". I also tried to do it again after a restart and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found everywhere but these steps helped me to resolve my issue of connecting my earphones to both my mobile and ubuntu laptop at same time.

If your Bluetooth earphones connected successfully but are not showing up in the output section of the sound settings, you can try the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

1. **Check for updates**: Make sure your Ubuntu system is up to date. Open a terminal and run the following commands:

   `sudo apt update`

   `sudo apt upgrade`
2. **Restart Bluetooth services**: Restart the Bluetooth services by running these commands in the terminal:

   `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`

   `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart`
3. Install additional Bluetooth packages: Make sure all necessary Bluetooth packages are installed. Run the following commands in the terminal:

   `sudo apt install --reinstall pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`

   `sudo apt install bluez blueman pavucontrol`
4. **Restart PulseAudio**: Restart the PulseAudio sound server by running these commands:

   `pulseaudio -k`

   `pulseaudio --start`
5. **Connect your earphones**: If you haven't connected your earphones already, do so now by going to the Bluetooth settings in the system settings menu. If you have already connected them, disconnect and reconnect them.
6. **Check sound settings**: Open the sound settings and see if your earphones are now listed as an output device. If they are still not showing up, open PulseAudio Volume Control (pavucontrol) and check under the "Configuration" tab if your earphones are listed and set to the correct profile (usually "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP)"). If you don't have pavucontrol installed, you can install it using the command:

   `sudo apt install pavu`

Comment: @David I tried to answer as concise as possible. Took me 2 hours to figure this out. No one answered step by step concise answer. All were just few steps here and there. When I ran these steps in this order the problem resolved. And FYI the latest ubuntu still has this problem every time you connect your bluetooth headphone/earphones.