# PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I get this error after installing new updates. This is the output of VLC:

```
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28)
[0x2100668] pulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
[0x2029118] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x7f86fc001078] access_http access: Raw-audio server found,  demuxer selected
[0x7f86fcc04c88] es demux error: cannot peek
[0x7f86fcc04c88] es demux error: cannot peek
[0x203cc48] main playlist: stopping playback
[0x7f86fcc170b8] access_http access: Raw-audio server found, m4a demuxer selected
[0x7f86fcc13878] packetizer_mpeg4audio demux packetizer: AAC channels: 2 samplerate: 22050
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
[0x2100668] alsa audio output error: cannot open ALSA device "default": Device or resource busy
[0x2100668] main audio output error: module not functional
[0x7f86fcc1df98] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
```

I get similar errors from Gmusicbrowser as well. I tried the solution suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70560/why-am-i-getting-this-connection-to-pulseaudio-failed-error) without avail. Reinstalled VLC, Alsa and Pulse Audio but again no help.

Comment: Despite Alsa also failing in your vlc startup could you try specifying this as an output device from: Tools --> Preferences --> Audio --> Output --> Output Module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalled Ubuntu after spending so much times looking for a solution.