# Sound not working, pulseaudio is not working daemon cannot be killed because directory doesn't exist

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, speakers, pavucontrol

So I am really stuck on what to do. I installed ubuntu following the instructions on http://www.jfwhome.com/2016/01/04/latest-steps-to-install-ubuntu-on-the-asus-t100ta/ including using the sound file he provided. The speakers show up if I go to alsamixer and press f6, but I can't choose a different default card and speaker test doesn't work.

I also made my scrollbars bigger according to [How do I get a bigger static scrollbar (aka normal scrollbar)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775201/how-do-i-get-a-bigger-static-scrollbar-aka-normal-scrollbar)

when I open pavucontrol I get the same screen as [Why am I getting this "Connection to PulseAudio failed" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70560/why-am-i-getting-this-connection-to-pulseaudio-failed-error) for half a second then it says 'establishing connection to PulseAudio, Please wait...' and buffers indefinitely. It also has two other errors. I think it is also made my scrollbars bigger according to [How do I get a bigger static scrollbar (aka normal scrollbar)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775201/how-do-i-get-a-bigger-static-scrollbar-aka-normal-scrollbar) first I followed "Dorian"'s method, but that didn't work, so I followed pauljohn32's method and that worked, but I didn't know what numbers to put in to revert the changes I did following Dorian, but the sound didn't work before that. Anyway the errors are:

```
(pavucontrol:2775): Gtk-WARNING **: 01:32:40:808: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:26:25: The style property GtkRange:slider-width is depreciated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version


(pavucontrol:2775): Gtk-WARNING **: 01:32:40:808: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:27:25: The style property GtkRange:stepper-size is depreciated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
```

what do the numbers like 27:25 mean? and the 2775? I am a neophyte sorry.
more code I tried

```
~$ pactl list short sinks
Connection failure: Connection terminated
```

I also find that when I connect to bluetooth it connects for an instant and then says disconnected, not failed to connect.

```
~$ pulseaudio --start
```

works with no output, but

```
~$ pulseaudio -k 
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such file or directory
```

And of course I need to include

```
~$ speaker-test

speaker-test 1.1.3

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection terminated

Playback open error: -111,Connection refuse
```

I have tried a couple more things, such as reinstalling it and deleting everything in .config/pulse/, any ideas?