Switching microphone input device fails in udev script
I have a Sony WH-1000XM3 blue tooth headset. Every time I turn it on the microphone is set to "Internal". This is my laptop microphone which is awful. Now I manually go and change the the input device to "Headset WH-1000XM3", and everything works, but this manual process is tedious.
Audio settings:

Now I have a command which does the switching correctly:
pactl set-card-profile bluez_card.94_DB_56_19_07_F9 handsfree_head_unit

I have plugged this command into a script triggered by udev when the headset connects:
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10 # wait for the headset to fully connect                                 

pactl set-card-profile bluez_card.94_DB_56_19_07_F9 handsfree_head_unit &>> /tmp/pactl-log

but I get the following error:
$ cat /tmp/pactl-log
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused

I tried switching the user in the script with sudo -u myuserid pactl... but I get the same error.

Probably this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/602706/114435

(relevant answer in the duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/a/750624/380067)

Thanks a bunch. The missing XDG_RUNTIME_DIR from my command caused the issue, as described in the first link you posted:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457946/pactl-works-in-userspace-not-as-root-on-i3/602706#602706
It works now

I'm glad you fixed it! Could you please accept to close the question as a duplicate of the question I linked, so that other users will be redirected there when they find your question?

Done 1234567890
